# Can't get responseText from XHR object

Tags: javascript

I want to get the response text from php. I see it in the console as "responseText", but I can't get from my function codes variable.

When I run this code, `console.log(query(path,"GET"))`, I see response in the screenshot. When I run this code `console.log(query(path,"GET").responseText)`, I see only blank response.

#### PHP Code

```
<?php echo "Hi this is PHP Answer from Async XHR  request "; ?>
```

#### JavaScript Code

```
query=function(url,method){
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.url=url
    xhr.open(method,url,true)
    xhr.send()
    return xhr;
}

path="../../core/ajax/periyodikTarama.php"
console.log(query(path,"GET"))
```

#### Console Result

See the selected red text

[image]

Comment: Probably because the request hasn't been resolved. Add an if statement `if (xhr.readyState === 4) { return xhr }` and then try to get the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: XHR is async, so you will need to print out the response from a success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but this is the proper way to handle the async response with a callback.

```js
query = function(url, method, callbackFn) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.url = url;
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    callbackFn(xhr.responseText); // Feed the response to the callback
  }
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}

path = "../../core/ajax/periyodikTarama.php"
query(path, "GET", (responseText) => {
  console.log(responseText); // Log the resonse text
})
```